# Ajax calls and 403s

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, http-status-code-403

I have added a few (4-5) ajax calls to a site that previously did not have that many (maybe 1-2).

When I'm load testing this site with about 45 concurrent users I'm seeing a lot of 403 errors being reported and these occur quite often on the pages requested by ajax although not exclusively.

This is .net MVC site on a Windows 2012 server running IIS 8 with 10gb RAM and a decent CPU.

If I visit those pages or run test POSTs to them I never get a 403, it seems to be related to traffic levels.

Does anyone know if this is some automatic throttling in IIS or is there something I should be doing in my ajax calls to make sure they do not get marked as 403 for whatever reason.

Comment: You are going to need the subcode from the status.  I was thinking it could be a 403.9 (too many users).

Comment: 403.501 is the subcode.

Comment: As a result of looking further into the subcode I think I might have found the source of this issue. Our IIS8  (and maybe earlier versions as well) has dynamic IP restrictions turned on and the settings seem to correspond to what could be triggering these errors.